# sequentially deploy war on Tomcat on every time when its restart a server also specified order

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have multiple war files to deploy, for example. coll.war, egg.war, etc., each one will specify an application module.

In our application I have some specification that coll.war should deploy first and rest has to deploy in specific sequence such like.

```
coll.war
egg.war
chick.war
```

Can somebody help me out to do it with my sequence process when i will start a tomcat server.

Comment: @AurA i m still facing error and not getting a proper answer of this question so that i m waiting for proper answer form this community, can you explain how its possible??

Comment: Another post should you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698646/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-a-deployment-order-in-tomcat6

Comment: still cant get a solution of my problem as well my question...