# Starting web applications in order on tomcat 8.x

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there any way one can configure `tomcat 8.x` to start two web applications in desired order? For example, I have an two web applications A and B and I want to make sure that B always starts before A.

Comment: Google for "Tomcat deploy order". You'll find some SO threads like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698646/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-a-deployment-order-in-tomcat6

Comment: Check %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/server.xml ... but this "starts" is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order in file: "tomcat_home"/conf/server.xml and try to invert B with A