# IntelliJ Tomcat Deployment Order of Artifacts

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea, artifacts

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the default startup/deployment ordering of artifacts in IntelliJ (I'm on IJ 11).  It looks like it uses basic string ordering (ascending) to deploy the artifacts and it does so sequentially.  I want to change it up a bit so I can control the order in which my artifacts are started.

I've searched the web and stack overflow for this and haven't found an answer.  (SO Link: [How to control webapp deployment order when restarting tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539245/how-to-control-webapp-deployment-order-when-restarting-tomcat))

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was resolved for JBoss recently: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-36080. You may want to submit a new request to YouTrack so that this feature is also implemented for Tomcat.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that...but I'm a bit surprised it's not in there for tomcat too.  thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not there because no one has asked for it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because it turns out this feature was not implemented for Tomcat.  I submitted a feature request for it and you can track it at this link: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89803#comment=27-367677

Comment: Do you have any idea if the deployment order of artifacts has been resolved for GlassFish too ?

Comment: Do you have any idea if the deployment order of artifacts has been resolved for GlassFish too ? As of IntelliJ 13.1 I do not see any option to reorder the artifacts for Glassfish App Server !